# compile webkit error related with libWebKitSystemInterfaceMountainLion.a

Tags: webkit

When I build the WebKit on my macbook pro 10.8.2, I encounter the following problem. What happen? Thank you very much.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -L/Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug -L/Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/Source/WebKit/../../WebKitLibraries -F/Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug -F/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -filelist /Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WebKit.LinkFileList -Xlinker --no-demangle -exported_symbols_list /Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug/DerivedSources/WebKit/WebKit.LP64.exp -install_name /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -dead_strip -licucore -framework JavaScriptCore -framework QuartzCore -framework WebCore -sub_umbrella WebCore -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework Security -lWebKitSystemInterfaceMountainLion -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -framework WebCore -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGL -licucore -framework JavaScriptCore -framework IOKit -framework DiskArbitration -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 538.1 -o /Users/pro/MyWork/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__kCFURLCachePartitionKey", referenced from:
      _WKCachePartitionKey in libWebKitSystemInterfaceMountainLion.a(WebKitSystemInterface.o)
  "__CFHostIsDomainTopLevel", referenced from:
      _WKIsPublicSuffix in libWebKitSystemInterfaceMountainLion.a(WebKitSystemInterface.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be having an older copy WebKitLibraries. Try upgrading them and giving the build a try again. WebKitLibraries are located in the root directory of Webkit source. You can either copy them over from trunk or use the scripts (update-webkit-auxiliary-libs, update-webkit-support-libs).

Also, do remember to follow the build instructions mentioned on the [webkit site](http://www.webkit.org/building/build.html).

Hope it helps.